# How to route two DHCP interfaces to two different networks

Tags: linux-networking, lxc, cloud-init, lxd

I use `LXD` and `cloud-init` to configure an instance with two interfaces which get assigned IP's via DHCP.

- `eth0` (10.23.44.177/24) which is connected to a bridge on the host machine (lxdbr0) to get out to the internet.
- `enp5s0` (192.168.100.179) which connects to another node on a private LAN with no internet access.

My problem is that I can ping 8.8.8.8 or an ip on the private LAN, but they both severely lag, won't work for 10 seconds, then makes a ping, then nothing for a bit. If I turn one of the two interfaces off, the other works perfectly fine. I'm sure something is wrong w/ my routing.

Here's some info.

```
$ ip route s
default via 192.168.100.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.179 metric 100
default via 10.23.44.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.23.44.177 metric 100
10.23.44.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.23.44.177
10.23.44.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.23.44.177 metric 100
192.168.100.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.179
192.168.100.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.100.179 metric 100

$ ifconfig
enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.100.179  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
    inet6 fe80::216:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 144  bytes 15102 (15.1 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 705  bytes 55690 (55.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.23.44.177  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.23.44.255
    inet6 fd42:45c6:df12:80cb:216:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:16:3e:12:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 15620  bytes 95337338 (95.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 10186  bytes 740093 (740.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 182  bytes 17262 (17.2 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 182  bytes 17262 (17.2 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Can anyone offer some help on fixing my routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting two default gateways from your two DHCP servers, thus your machine has two default routes with equal metric; it doesn't know which one is preferred and tries to use both of them, with mixed results.

You need to remove this route:

```
default via 192.168.100.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.100.179 metric 100
```

However, this is given to you by a DHCP server, thus it could become difficult to get rid of it permanently; you'll probably need a script that removes the route after the interface goes up.

If you have control of the DHCP server on the 192.168.100.0/24 private network, you should configure it to not give you a default gateway. Otherwise, you'll need to remove the route after it has been given to you.